# How to import a text file to a 3-d matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a text file where in the data is of the format x/y/z/value.

say for ex. 0/0/0/12.0

How to import it to matlab such that I get it as a 3-d matrix having the **value** as the corresponding (x,y,z) value

Comment: What you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, import your 2D matrix of coordinates/values into Matlab, possibly using [dlmread](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html).

```
M = dlmread(filename, '/');
```

As noted by Shai you will want to convert the coordinates to 1-offset rather than 0-offset:

```
M(:,1:3) = M(:,1:3) + 1;
```

Next, create an appropriately sized matrix to insert your values into.

```
foo = zeros(max(M(:,1)), max(M(:,2)), max(M(:,3)));
```

Finally, convert your your coordinates to indeces using [sub2ind](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html), and insert the values.

```
idx = sub2ind(size(foo), M(:,1), M(:,2), M(:,3));
foo(idx) = M(:,4);
```

Comment: I see the indices values in the example starts from zero and not one - you might need to add + to `M(:,1:3)`

Comment: Thanks i am pretty much new to matlab just wanted this for the isosurface..:D